# error TS2769: No overload matches this call Overload 1 of 5, '(value: string | FormControlState<string>, opts: FormControlOptions

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-validation, angular15

I am learning Angular.
I follow the example at

https://www.angulartraining.com/daily-newsletter/rxjs-debouncetime-operator/

https://stackblitz.com/edit/at-debouncetime?file=app%2Fcreditcardvalidator.directive.ts,app%2Fapp.component.html,app%2Fapp.component.ts

which is ok at version 5.0.0.
However, compiling it with version 15.1.0 get the following errors.
How to fix it?

```
Error: src/app/app.component.ts:16:5 - error TS2769: No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 5, '(value: string | FormControlState<string>, opts: FormControlOptions & { nonNullable: true; }): FormControl<string>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '(control: FormControl<any>) => ValidationErrors | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'FormControlOptions & { nonNullable: true; }'.
      Type '(control: FormControl<any>) => ValidationErrors | null' is not assignable to type '{ nonNullable: true; }'.
  Overload 2 of 5, '(value: string | FormControlState<string>, opts: FormControlOptions & { initialValueIsDefault: true; }): FormControl<string>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '(control: FormControl<any>) => ValidationErrors | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'FormControlOptions & { initialValueIsDefault: true; }'.
      Type '(control: FormControl<any>) => ValidationErrors | null' is not assignable to type '{ initialValueIsDefault: true; }'.
  Overload 3 of 5, '(value: string | FormControlState<string>, validatorOrOpts?: ValidatorFn | ValidatorFn[] | FormControlOptions | null | undefined, asyncValidator?: AsyncValidatorFn | ... 2 more ... | undefined): FormControl<...>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '(control: FormControl<any>) => ValidationErrors | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ValidatorFn | ValidatorFn[] | FormControlOptions | null | undefined'.
      Type '(control: FormControl<any>) => ValidationErrors | null' is not assignable to type 'ValidatorFn'.
        Types of parameters 'control' and 'control' are incompatible.
          Type 'AbstractControl<any, any>' is missing the following properties from type 'FormControl<any>': defaultValue, registerOnChange, registerOnDisabledChange

16     CreditCardValidator.validateCcNumber
       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  src/app/app.component.ts:16:5
    16     CreditCardValidator.validateCcNumber
           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Did you mean to call this expression?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution 1: Cast as `ValidatorFn`**

```js
cardControl: FormControl = new FormControl(
  '',
  CreditCardValidator.validateCcNumber as ValidatorFn
);
```

---

**Solution 2: Migrate the `validateCcNumber` to return as `ValidatorFn`**

```js
static validateCcNumber(): ValidatorFn {
  return (control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null => {

    // Implementation
    if (
      !(
        control.value.startsWith('37') ||
        control.value.startsWith('4') ||
        control.value.startsWith('5')
      )
    ) {
      // Return error if card is not Amex, Visa or Mastercard
      return {
        creditCard:
          'Your credit card number is not from a supported credit card provider',
      };
    } else if (control.value.length !== 16) {
      console.log(control.value);
      // Return error if length is not 16 digits
      return { creditCard: 'A credit card number must be 16-digit long' };
    }
    // If no error, return null
    return null;
  };
}
```

```js
cardControl: FormControl = new FormControl(
  '',
  CreditCardValidator.validateCcNumber()
);
```

[Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zuxhqi?file=src/creditcardvalidator.directive.ts)

Comment: @ Yong Shun
Thank you very much!!! Excellent!!!
Compile error is fixed.
validateCcNumber work.
validateCcNumber2 do not seem to work:
the message 'Your credit card number is not from a supported credit card provider' do not appear.

Comment: Hi @albertkao9, I had revised my answer. For Solution 2, should use `CreditCardValidator.validateCcNumber2()`.

Comment: @ Yong Shun
Thank you very much!!! Excellent!!!
validateCcNumber and validateCcNumber2 work!